# How do you create a pushtopic query with global variables?

Tags: soql, force.com, streaming-api

Intuitively I would think this is how to do it, but it does not work.

```
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT id, name, Doer__c from Object1__c WHERE Doer__c =: UserInfo.getUserId()'; 
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 29.0;
```

**Error:**

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INVALID_FIELD, unexpected token: ':': [Query]: AnonymousBlock:
>   line 9, column 1

Comment: Have you tried storing `UserInfo.getUserId()` in a variable and then binding against the variable? Also, what context is this running in? A VF controller?

Answer (score 6):

While evaluating the variable and then substituting it might help the creation of one, your PushTopics are ultimately going to proliferate (and you must hoover them up as your users change).

Why not use Streaming API filtered subscriptions? You can insert a PushTopic like:

```
insert new PushTopic(
    Name        = 'Doers',
    Query       = 'SELECT Id, Doer__c FROM Object1__c', //WHERE <snip>
    ApiVersion  = 29.0
);
```

**[Update:](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34826/streaming-api-mvel-operators/34913?noredirect=1#comment116530_34913)**

> basic filtering available in the form:
>
> ```
> /topic/MyTopic?User__c=005A0000000gqi6IAA
> ```
>
> Conditions can be combined by using an `&` for example:
>
> ```
> /topic/MyTopic?User__c=005A0000000gqi6IAA&Id={ID-18Char}
> ```
>
> This translates into OR condition: `User__c == 005A0000000gqi6IAA OR Id == {ID-18Char}`
>
> This is not nearly as robust as MVEL operations but can help reduce the number of received events

Comment: tip: don't URL encode the topic string or the MVEL operators

Comment: Note: MVEL has been disabled but see my comment on the following post for basic filter operations. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34826/streaming-api-mvel-operators