# Streaming API MVEL Operators

Tags: streaming-api

Do the MVEL operators for filtered subscriptions [described in Streaming API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_filtered_subscriptions.htm) really work?

I've tried a few variations of this (i.e. with/without quotes, double/single == etc.):

```
j$.cometd.subscribe("/topic/MyTopic?User__c=='{!$User.Id}'", callback);
```

And cannot get it to work (i.e. I cannot filter the records by user, I get ALL records). Does anyone have any experience of using this successfully?

**EDIT:**

To make sure I hadn't missed anything, I tried subscribing (separately) as follows:

```
j$.cometd.subscribe("/topic/MyTopic?User__c=='{!$User.Id}'", callback);
j$.cometd.subscribe("/topic/MyTopic?User__c=={!$User.Id}", callback);
j$.cometd.subscribe("/topic/MyTopic?User__c='{!$User.Id}'", callback);
j$.cometd.subscribe("/topic/MyTopic?User__c={!$User.Id}", callback);
```

I examined the Request Payload using Chrome and it appears that nothing has gone awry:

```
[{  "channel":"/meta/subscribe",
    "subscription":"/topic/MyTopic?User__c=='005A0000000gqi6IAA'",
    "id":"2",
    "clientId":"85d1vkpu673gnvdq1mt73bp37xyz" }]
```

And still, each time I still get ALL records instead of filtered by my User ID.

Comment: I've used MVEL operators with the [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/browser.html) client successfully. Can you inspect the network traffic and confirm the cometd client is not URL encoding your apostrophes? Or that it's not trashing the entire query string?

Comment: Yep, good idea - will take a squizz and update - cheers dude

Comment: Is the PushTopic you inserted of a sufficient API version to support MVEL operator filters?

Comment: Yes, pushTopic.ApiVersion = 29.0;

Comment: hmm, can you post exact code (client and server) as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)? perhaps a dump of sample data?

Comment: Will do...though there really isn't much too it

Comment: Did anyone have any luck with this? I tried different formats using && and || conditions too but it didn't work.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not - I ended up going down a different route because streaming ended up generally not being reliable enough for my use case (e.g. doesn't guarantee delivery).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Update:](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34826/streaming-api-mvel-operators/34913?noredirect=1#comment116530_34913)**

> basic filtering available in the form:
>
> ```
> /topic/MyTopic?User__c=005A0000000gqi6IAA
> ```
>
> Conditions can be combined by using an `&` for example:
>
> ```
> /topic/MyTopic?User__c=005A0000000gqi6IAA&Id={ID-18Char}
> ```
>
> This translates into OR condition: `User__c == 005A0000000gqi6IAA OR Id == {ID-18Char}`
>
> This is not nearly as robust as MVEL operations but can help reduce the number of received events

[John Brock](https://twitter.com/_johnbrock/status/516598722747453440) from Salesforce confirms that MVEL Operators have been removed from the Salesforce Streaming API for the time being. They are looking into other options.

The last time I saw this working was API 27.0 and using an old `PushTopic` version or an old subscription header may not work either. Thanks to [Andrew Fawcett](https://twitter.com/andyinthecloud/status/516597279487455232) for confirming this.

Comment: Cheers Matt & Andy

Comment: bigassforce is correct -- we are currently investigating potential options to improve or replace MVEL filtering. MVEL has been disabled for all API versions so using v27 will not work.

Comment: Note: we do have basic filtering available in the form of:
/topic/MyTopic?User__c=005A0000000gqi6IAA
Conditions can be combined by using an '&' ie: /topic/MyTopic?User__c=005A0000000gqi6IAA&Id={ID-18Char} which translates into and OR condition: User__c == 005A0000000gqi6IAA OR Id == {ID}. This is not nearly as robust as MVEL operations but it can help reduce the number of received events.

Comment: This is super! Thanks for the good news @JohnBrock